# Open a docx file in browser instead of desktop app

Tags: office365

I don't have office installed, nor will install it. I want to double-click a file and open it on Teams or browser instead.

I don't want the solution "if you are in share point" or "from Teams, click on..."

I want to open my Windows explorer, double-click the file and open it either on browser or Teams app